# How to get the linear regression equation for a certain variable?

Tags: r, linear-regression

When trying to retreive a linear regression equation I keep getting this error:

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'OBP' not found

Here is my chunk,

```
teams_oak %>%
  select(G:FP) %>% 
  mutate(OBP=H+BB+HBP/AB+BB+HBP+SF) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=OBP,y=W))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  labs(title="OBP vs. Wins in MLB 1982-2002 ex:1994",x="On Base Percentage",y="Wins") %>% 

  teams_oak %>%
  select(G:FP) %>% 
  mutate(OBP=H+BB+HBP/AB+BB+HBP+SF) %>% 
  m1<-lm(data = teams_oak,formula = W~OBP)
```

I've tried to pipe all the functions together to make sure that the code was reading for the mutated variable and it seems it cannot find it.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(teams_oak, 20))`

Comment: I think the `%>%` at the end is causing the issue.  Remove that and your `m1 <- lm(data = teams_oak, ...)` should work.  If you want to find that use `%>% with(., lm(W~ OBP))` or use %$% lm(W~ OBP)` i.e. `iris %$% lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species)`

Comment: divID = c("W", "E", "E", "W", "W", "E", "W", "E", "E", "W", 
    "W", "W", "W", "E", "E", "E", "E", "W", "E", "E"), Rank = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    6L, 5L, 2L, 4L), G = c(162L, 163L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 
    162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 163L, 162L, 162L, 
    162L, 162L, 162L, 162L), Ghome = c(81L, 82L, 81L, 81L, 80L, 
    81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 
    81L, 81L, 81L), W = c(89L, 94L, 89L, 93L, 87L, 73L, 61L, 
    78L, 83L, 77L, 90L, 88L, 60L, 95L, 86L, 79L, 65L, 68L,

Comment: I guess the comment above should work with `library(magrittr)` and `%$%` or using `with`.  The dput is not complete, so it can't be tested

Comment: There are at least 2 incorrect pipes `%>%` in your example code. One after the `labs()` line, should probably not be there. For the second block, you should assign to `m1` at the start of the code block and pipe into `lm` at the end, with `data = .` for the data argument to `lm`.

Comment: Please don't add data or information relevant to the post as a comment. Use the Edit option for your post to add the data sample to the body of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
  teams_oak %>%
  select(G:FP) %>% 
  mutate(OBP=H+BB+HBP/AB+BB+HBP+SF) %>% 
  m1<-lm(data = teams_oak,formula = W~OBP)
```

on the last two lines you are using the pipe operator with an assignment on the last line. Within that assignment you are naming `teams_oak` as the data, but because this is in the pipe and the pipe hasn't finished yet, it doesn't have the OBP variable, so it fails.

I think simply omitting the last pipe operator and turning it into two assigment statements, should work, with a blank line and indentation to indicate the end of the pipe

```
  teams_oak <- teams_oak %>%
    select(G:FP) %>% 
    mutate(OBP=H+BB+HBP/AB+BB+HBP+SF)

  m1<-lm(data = teams_oak,formula = W~OBP)
```

Personally I don't use pipes because it does make it easy to break code this way. They are not the best way to write clear code.

Comment: I did that and I still get the same error:   Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'OBP' not found. I do get what you are saying about the space. I just don't know what argument I can run to make OBP retrievable

Comment: With my code, check the names of the column in `teams_oak` after the pipe. If it doesn't have an OBP column then the mutate is broken. You should always be in a position to inspect your objects before you do stuff to check your assumptions.

Comment: This worked! Just started coding a month ago, so I'm fairly new to r. Thanks for the help